# Why should I call EVP_DigestInit rather than calling hash functions directly?

Tags: c++, hash, openssl

In [OpenSSL documentation for SHA512](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/SHA512.html) there's written following recommendation:

> Applications should use the higher level functions EVP_DigestInit(3) etc. instead of calling the hash functions directly.

What is the reason for that? It's safer? There is no explanation why I should use IT.

I want to make SHA512 hash and according to this recommendation, I should use for computing this hash EVP_* functions instead of SHA512_* functions. Or did I understand it wrong?

```
SHA512_CTX m_context;
SHA512_Init(&m_context)
SHA512_Update(&m_context, data, size)
SHA512_Final(hash, &m_context);


auto m_context = EVP_MD_CTX_create();
EVP_DigestInit_ex(m_context, EVP_get_digestbyname("sha512"), NULL);
EVP_DigestUpdate(m_context, data, size);
EVP_DigestFinal_ex(m_context, hash, NULL);
```

Comment: Because the simplicity of using higher-level functions rather than using the low-level API (which can be error-prone and take more time to get right and which can make the code more vulnerable or generally harder to maintain)?

Comment: That's the problem, I don't think using higher-level functions in this case is simpler. :) I'm going to edit question.

Answer (score 1):

I asked the same thing and here is their answer
https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/12260

For a number of reasons. For example:

In some cases you get sub-optimal implementations with the low-level APIs vs the EVP APIs. An example from the "cipher" world (but the same concept applies to digests) is the low-level function AES_encrypt. If you call that you will never get the AESNI optimized version which may be available on your platform.

We want to encourage applications to use a consistent API for all types of digests/ciphers etc. This makes it much easier for everyone to update code as security advice changes. For example you mention the MD5 digest APIs. MD5 is no longer recommended. It's a lot harder to update your code to use some other digest if you've used the low-level APIs vs the high level ones. Looking into the future imagine some algorithm has some major flaw discovered in it that requires a rapid migration away from it to some other algorithm. We want the OpenSSL ecosystem to be as agile as possible to be able to deal with that.

The old APIs no longer fits architecturally with how OpenSSL 3.0 works. All algorithm implementations are now made available by "providers" in OpenSSL 3.0 - for example we have the "default" provider, the "fips" provider and a "legacy" provider. The low level APIs circumvent all of that which means we have to maintain 2 ways of doing everything (3 actually when you bring ENGINEs into the picture as well). This leads to unnecessary code bloat and complexity....which is definitely something you want to avoid in a crypto library. Ideally we would have removed the old ways completely - but that would have been too big a breaking change.